# Monitor shows "no signal" when i try to power on my PC

Tags: monitor

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS yesterday. I'm very new to all this linux stuff. So yeah when i installed it works completely fine and then I shut it down and after sometime when I try to power on, my monitor show no signal message and gets in to sleep mode. I have tried changing monitors but the issue continues. I have also tried changing the VGA Adapter but there is no use. CPU specifications are 4gb RAM, core 2 duo processor.

Can somebody just explain me what's happening with my pc.

Comment: Do you see the bios messages on the screen, after turning on the computer?

Comment: No. There was not any bios messages and I can't even get to the bios settings(for reinstallation). It shows only Acer(my monitor) name and then it displays a "no signal" message and it goes into sleep mode ig

Comment: In this case it is not an ubuntu problem. My hint: As the computer is older, check the Bios battery (onboard).

Comment: Yes. It is not an ubuntu problem. I get it now. But how do I get if the bios battery working fine or not? Sorry I don't know much about these things.

Comment: Safety first, unplug the power!! If you have no clue, ask somebody near you with more knowledge. Open (unplug the power!!) the computer, look for the battery (usually a CR2032). Replace it. Close the computer and try again. If it is not easy to replace, contact a technician from the computer manufacturer.

Comment: Hey! I changed the bios battery and now "going to sleep mode" problem is gone.. thanks to you.. but now my pc is stuck at "motherboard logo" and I can't get past that. I would try to get into bios but the I can't operate keyboard.

Comment: Without additional details about the computer nobody can help you. As it is a new question, best to create a new question for this. I will add my comment as answer and I would be happy if you accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As the computer is older, check/replace the Bios battery (onboard).

Safety first, unplug the power!! If you have no clue, ask somebody near you with more knowledge. Open (unplug the power!!) the computer, look for the battery (usually a CR2032). Replace it. Close the computer and try again. If it is not easy to replace, contact a technician from the computer manufacturer.